# Internal django website access external resources via proxy server

Tags: python, django, apache, proxy

I have a django website that's served on an internal network. This is being served via the standard `apache2` with `mod_wsgi` setup.

However, this server sits behind a proxy, and I need to be able to access external resources via this app, for example, fetch resources from the internet, say, via `urllib`.

How do I configure the django app to use the `http_proxy` settings?

Comment: You don't configure Django to use a proxy when jQuery wants to access external resources. That's a matter of the browser. …Or maybe you just explained the problem poorly.

Comment: It's in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html